# Transparent BackColor for TrackBar

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I added picturebox and label to the form and set picturebox like parent object of label. And then I can set transparent background colour on label.

```
label1.Parent = pictureBox1;
label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

I can do it with `Label`, `CheckBox` but cannot do it with **`TrackBar`**. And I cannot understand - why and how to solve it.

Comment: That controls doesn't support transparent colors. It's constructor doesn't add [ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles) when [Control.SetStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle) is called (it also sets `SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, false`)). Not all controls support a transparent color. It depends on how they're rendered.

Comment: So, it cant be solved?

Comment: What *problem* do you need to solve? The background color of the TrackBar control is already set to the BackColor of its Parent. You can create a custom control derived from TrackBar and set the style. Not sure what you want to accomplish with this, though. Maybe, see the [TrackBarRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.trackbarrenderer) Class.

Comment: The background color of the trackBar is background color of the form, isnt it? But I need to use transporent color (to see the picture under trackBar).

Comment: You'ld have a hard time taming that control. Maybe, revisit your design or look for an OpenSource control that implements the functionality/behavior/appearance you're looking for. You could also consider WPF. Its Slider is probably easier to handle. If you know WPF, of course.

Comment: Trackbar is an olden native Windows control, it uses 24bpp GDI under the hood to render itself.  It requires an opaque background.  Creating your own trackbar from Control is a somewhat useful exercise.  Google "windows forms custom trackbar" if you don't want to do it yourself.